# How to pass parameters with JSF AJAX response as native ajax requests

Tags: ajax, jsf, parameter-passing

I want to send back (add some parameter) some value with JSF ajax response as native JSF ajax and jQuery ajax. How to do it? I'm using JSF 2.2, if that's relevant.

Comment: primefaces has some interesting features. does it need to be strictly vanilla JSF?

Comment: All JSF ajax aware components support passing parameters. The *how* depends on how you're sending the ajax request. This information is unfortunately entirely missing in the question, which makes your question unanswerable. Also, mentioning jQuery is confusing as this has got completely nothing to do with native JSF ajax.

Comment: so there is no way to parse the argument with jsf ajax?

Comment: All JSF ajax aware components support passing parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<f:param>` inside buttons.

```
<h:commandButton value="Send">
    <f:param name="c" value="#{bean.value}"/>
    <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{bean.listener}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```